# Mongoose-MongoDb : doc.pull inconsistent when multiple pull

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

node v7.7.1
mongodb: 2.2.33,
mongoose: 4.13.7

Hello all,

i'm having this unexpected behaviour when trying to update a document with multiple pull request based on matching criterias. here is what i mean

my document schma looks like this

```
{
    "_id": "5a1c0c37d1c8b6323860dfd0",
    "ID": "1511781786844",
    "main": {
        "_id": "5a3c37bfc065e86a5c593967",
        "plan": [
            {
                "field1": 1,
                "field2": 1,
                "_id": "5a3c30dfa479bb4b5887e56e",
                "child": []
            },
            {
                "field1": 1,
                "field2": 2,
                "_id": "5a3c30e1a479bb4b5887e5c",
                "child": []
            },
            {
                "field1": 1,
                "field2": 3,
                "_id": "5a3c37bfc065e86a5c593968",
                "child": []
            },
            {
                "field1": 1,
                "field2": 4,
                "_id": "5a3c37bfc065e86a5c593655",
                "child": []
            },
            {
                "field1": 1,
                "field2": 5,
                "_id": "5a3c30dfa479bb4b5887e56f",
                "child": []
            },
            {
                "field1": 1,
                "field2": 6,
                "_id": "5a3c30e1a479bb4b6887e545",
                "child": []
            },
            {
                "field1": 1,
                "field2": 7,
                "_id": "5a3c37bfc065e86a5c5939658",
                "child": []
            },
            {
                "field1": 2,
                "field2": 2,
                "_id": "5a3c37bfc065e86a5c593963",
                "child": []
            },
        ]
    },
        ...
        ....
}
```

and this is my code to update the document:

```
Schema.findOne({ID: data.ID})
      .then(function(doc) {

        var array = doc.main.plan;

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if ( array[i].field1=== 1 )) {
            var id = array[i]._id;
            console.log('pulling');
            doc.pull( { _id: id });
        }
    }

    doc.save().then(function(doc) {
        console.log('saving');
        // console.log(doc);
        if (doc && doc.docID) {
            return { success: true };
        } else {
            return { success: false, error: 'unknownError'}
        }
    })
}
```

now the issue is let's say  my array has 7 objects that matches the test (array[i].theField === parseInt(updFields.theField)), when i run this and check the logs i see that it will basically pull half of the objects and do a save.

so i would get 
pulling
pulling
pulling
pulling
save.

and then i have to run the code for the remaining 3 objects in the array and get 
pulling
pulling
saving

so i have to run  it a third time to completely clear the array.

need help get this working

thank you

Answer (score 0):

So i created a little workaround by doing a recursive function to pull all with only one click using lodash functions. not pretty but it does the job.

```
const delObjArray = (doc, cond) => {
      const checkField = cond.field;
      const checkVal = cond.value;
      _.forEach(doc, (value) => {
        if (value && value[checkField] === checkVal) {
          doc.pull({ _id: value._id });
        }
      });
      const isFound = _.some(doc, { [checkField]: checkVal });
      if (isFound) {
        delObjArray(doc, cond);
      } else {
        return true;
      }
      return true;
    };
```